# How to get the total documents count, containing a specific field, using aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am moving from ElasticSearch 1.7 to 2.0. Previously while calculating Term Facets I got the Total Count as well. This will tell in how many documents  that field exists. This is how I was doing previously.

```
TermsFacet termsFacet = (TermsFacet) facet;
termsFacet.getTotalCount();
```

It worked with Multivalue field as well.

Now in current version for Term Aggregation we don't have anything as Total Count. I am getting DocCount inside Aggregation bucket. But that will  not work for muti-valued fields.

```
Terms termsAggr = (Terms) aggr;
for (Terms.Bucket bucket : termsAggr.getBuckets()) {
                    String bucketKey = bucket.getKey();
                    totalCount += bucket.getDocCount();
 }
```

Is there any way I can get Total count of the field from term aggregation.
I don't want to fire exists Filter query. I want result in single query.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the exists query:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-exists-query.html

For instance to find the documents that contain the field user you can use:

```
{
    "exists" : { "field" : "user" }
}
```

There is of course also a java API:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-term-level-queries.html#java-query-dsl-exists-query

```
QueryBuilder qb = existsQuery("name");
```

Comment: I think the OP mentioned that he didn't want to use "exists query". Is there any relevant aggregation to achieve the same? I think "TermsFacet" used to to give the desired values, but facets are no longer supported by ES.